# OS X Ukrainian spellcheck

Tags: spellcheck, spelling

I did some research and still have trouble to find any way to enable Ukrainian language spell check in OS X.

Please advise how to make it happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the .dic and .aff files from

https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries

And put them in $HOME/Library/Spelling

Comment: The dictionary does work if I choose it explicitly (i. e. it shows me errors in misspelled Ukrainian words). However, if I set "Automatically by Language" in spelling settings, it doesn't show me the errors anymore.
In my example, I use built-in TextEdit Version 1.17 (378) on MacOS Monterey (12.2.1).
Any ideas on how to make it work with the "Automatic by Language" setting?

Comment: @wheleph unfortunately only dictionaries supplied by Apple work with the “automatic” setting.  Ask them to fix that via http://www.apple.com/feedback